# Iteratively read excel files, calculate MAE and append to one dataframe using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Given [a folder](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjnopz1r7hwfhc0/preds.zip?dl=0) which contains 3 predictions result, one example as follows:

```
          date  real      pred indicator
0    2021/1/31   1.0  0.586583     train
1    2021/2/28   0.6  0.442644     train
2    2021/3/31  -0.5 -0.011877     train
3    2021/4/30  -0.3 -0.011877     train
4    2021/5/31  -0.2 -0.011877     train
5    2021/6/30  -0.4 -0.011877     train
6    2021/7/31   0.3  0.152951     train
7    2021/8/31   0.1  0.393088     train
8    2021/9/30   0.0  0.163108     train
9   2021/10/31   0.7  0.537028     valid
10  2021/11/30   0.4  0.586583     valid
```

I hope to loop and read all excel files, calculate `MAE` respectively for subset `train` and `valid` of each prediction file, and finally concatenate the calculated `MAE` values and excel file names.

Code I have done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
import os
from pathlib import Path
import re
import glob

file_paths = glob.glob('./preds/*.xlsx')
dfs = pd.DataFrame()

for file_path in file_paths:
    data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    # print(data)
    model_name = Path(file_path).stem
    print(model_name)
    
    train = data.loc[data['indicator'] == 'train']
    valid = data.loc[data['indicator'] == 'valid']
    
    print(mean_absolute_error(train['real'], train['pred']))
    print(mean_absolute_error(valid['real'], valid['pred']))
```

Out:

```
pred3
0.06462038177996876
0.14329840342203767
pred2
0.29968300930091313
0.20961438417434672
pred1
0.2807230830192565
0.1747779786586765
```

To create dataframe for save output:

```
col_names = ['model', 'train_mae', 'valid_mae']
dfs = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)
```

My question is how could I append the iteratively calculated `MAE` values to the final result? Thanks.

The expected result:

```
   model  mae_train  mae_valid
0  pred1   0.280723   0.174778
1  pred2   0.299683   0.209614
2  pred3   0.064620   0.143298
```

**EDIT:**

```
model_name = []
train_mae = []
test_mae = []

for file_path in file_paths:
    data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    # print(data)
    model_name = Path(file_path).stem
    print(model_name)

    train = data.loc[data['indicator'] == 'train']
    valid = data.loc[data['indicator'] == 'valid']

    print(mean_absolute_error(train['real'], train['pred']))
    print(mean_absolute_error(valid['real'], valid['pred']))

    train_mae = mean_absolute_error(train['real'], train['pred'])
    valid_mae = mean_absolute_error(valid['real'], valid['pred'])

    model_name.append(model_name)
    train_mae.append(train_mae)
    valid_mae.append(valid_mae)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(model_name , train_mae, valid_mae)),
           columns =['model', 'train_mae', 'valid_mae'])
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 23, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list of lists to store your information, then pass it to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
mae_data = []

for file_path in file_paths:
    data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    # print(data)
    model_name = Path(file_path).stem
    print(model_name)
    
    train = data.loc[data['indicator'] == 'train']
    valid = data.loc[data['indicator'] == 'valid']
    
    print(mean_absolute_error(train['real'], train['pred']))
    print(mean_absolute_error(valid['real'], valid['pred']))
    
    ## append [model_name, mae_train, mae_valid] to mae_list
    mae_data.append([model_name, mean_absolute_error(train['real'], train['pred']),mean_absolute_error(valid['real'], valid['pred'])])

col_names = ['model', 'train_mae', 'valid_mae']
dfs = pd.DataFrame(data=mae_data, columns=col_names)
```

Comment: This is much better, I'm considering to create 3 empty list to store values: `model_name = [], train_mae = [], test_mae = []`

Comment: I updated alternative solution, it raises an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`, do you know how to fix the issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ah bon you're getting this error because you're using the `model_name` variable name twice. you can instead call the list `model_name_list`

Comment: The list of `train_mae` should also be `train_mae_list`?

Comment: @ah bon yeah, you should make `train_mae_list` and `valid_mae_list` your lists